# jQuery tools scrollable root element relative positioned instead of absolute

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tools

I noticed on this page that it says the root element for scrollable items. Must be absolutely positioned. This is causing issues when trying to resize the scrollable items container according to the height of the child elements that scroll.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/

I simply changed position:absolute to position:relative so the container will respect the child height and that worked fine. It scrolls in all browsers fine. Am i missing something  here? Why is it mandatory to have it absolutely positioned? Its positioned relative to the container its in which works for me. Just looking for some input/thoughts.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual requirement is just to **be positioned** in order for the scrolling/paging to work.  The scrolling motion is done by animating the `left` style property. Without positioning, regardless whether `relative` or `absolute`, the negative left offset would have been ignored.

So it didn't break when you've changed to the `position: relative`. If you've removed the `position` declaration altogether, only then it would break and fail to scroll.